# no GRUB menu bootloader option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, bootloader

I have used ***Ubuntu*** distribution in my ***HP*** laptop along with ***Windows 7*** dual-boot before. But due to some mistakes while partitioning using windows default partition tool, I formatted my system drives and as a result I had no other choice than to reinstall everything. I first installed ***Windows 7*** and then installed ***Ubuntu*** on different partition drives. After I installed ***Ubuntu 14.04*** and restarted the system, there was no ***bootloader*** menu option. ***Windows 7*** was directly accessed without ***GRUB*** menu. I tried the ***boot-repair*** tool too but after I installed it there was no ***Recommended repair*** option neither the ***Advanced settings*** option. There was only ***Create a BootInfo Summary***.
Here is the URL for my ***BootInfo Summary*** [[http://paste.ubuntu.com/7548609/]](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7548609/%5d).